# Distribute and update an app to specifics users

Tags: android, google-play

I am looking for a solution to give the permission to specifics users to download and update my app in the PlayStore.

For example, adding the gmail account of the user in the Publisher Console to give the permission.

Is it possible ? How ?
Other solutions ? Maybe an other store ?

Comment: Look at beta testing in the play console.

Comment: Good idea! Is there a number limitation of the beta-testers ?

Comment: I don't think so, practically speaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up closed alpha or beta test. With closed beta testing, you can create a list of beta testers by email address. You can create up to 50 lists per track with up to 2,000 users in each. Look [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) for more.

Comment: Is there a number limitation of the beta-testers ?